# Tilemill mapnik export ignoring scale-factor

Tags: mapnik, tilemill

I have a tileserver (mapnik+tirex/mod_tile) running and stumbled on the problem that the map (mainly texts) is unreadable when printing images with 300 or 600 dpi pritn resolution because the tiles are rendered in screen resolution

So i generated a new profile in Tilemill using the scale property, but when exporting in mapnik xml format the tiles are not rendered with bigger texts like shown in tilemill workspace - seems like the export is writing the font sizes for scale-factor=1. In addition there doesn't seem to be a tirex option for generating tiles with another scale factor as workaround

Is there a way to export a mapnik style with the appropriate scale or a script to convert the style to a certain scale ?

Thanks

(btw, i know about the nik2img script but i need "print tiles" so this is not an option)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com)